# Post images from directory php

Tags: php, image, post, directory

I am very new to php and I would like to iterate through an images directory in the root folder and post these images to a webpage. I am using the following code to do so:

```
<?php
$dir = "images/*.jpg";
$images = glob( $dir );
foreach( $images as $image ):
  echo "<img src='" . $image . "' />";
endforeach;
?>
```

My question is how can I modify this code to post more than .jpg images, such as .gif and jpg with the .jpeg extension without creating multiple directory variables?

Also, is there a more efficient way to post these images?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The non clever brute force way to do this would be to just run the loop for all different image types.

```
$dir = "images/*.jpg";
$images = glob( $dir );
foreach( $images as $image ):
  echo "<img src='" . $image . "' />";
endforeach;
$dir = "images/*.png";
$images = glob( $dir );
foreach( $images as $image ):
  echo "<img src='" . $image . "' />";
endforeach;
$dir = "images/*.gif";
$images = glob( $dir );
foreach( $images as $image ):
  echo "<img src='" . $image . "' />";
endforeach;

etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way would be creating an array and then iterate it.

```
<?php
$imgs = array("images/*.jpg","images/*.gif","images/*.pnj");
foreach( $imgs as $type ){
   $images = glob( $type );
   foreach( $images as $image ):
      echo "<img src='" . $image . "' />";
   endforeach;
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: $files = glob("*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);

Answer (score 0):

As you are building an Array ($images is an array) you can push new files to this array.

```
$file_extensions = ['jpg', 'png'];

$images_total = [];
foreach ( $file_extensions as $extension ) {
    $dir = "images/*." . $extension;
    $images = glob( $dir );
    foreach $images as $image {
        $images_total[] = $image;
    }
}
```

And now use your final code:

```
<?php
foreach( $images_total as $image ):
    echo "<img src='" . $image . "' />";
endforeach;
?>
```

I didnt test it, but this is an idea :)

I reply appeared while I typed: As a difference, in my method you get to build an array containing every single file in the folder before start printing HTML. This may allow you to shuffle or maybe manipulate the array before outputting to the user :)